# Prove that the collection is a basis for the Euclidian topology.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the collection $$\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b)|a,b\in \mathbb{R},\; a<b\} \cup \{(-\infty, b)|b\in\mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(a,\infty)|a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$$ is a basis for the Euclidian topology.

I know that $\{(a,b)|a,b\in \mathbb{R},\; a<b\} $ is the basis for Euclidean topology, but does that imply that the above collection also a basis is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does:  Since sets of the form $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b,\infty)$ may be written as

$$(-\infty,a)=\bigcup_{n>|a|}^\infty (-n,a)$$
$$(b,\infty)=\bigcup_{n>|b|}^\infty (b,n)$$

we have that your topology is generated by the Euclidean topology, and clearly the converse is true as you already have all open intervals in your given topology.